# Why does Ruby on Rails spuriously raise "Unable to Autoload Constant" after editing code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Autoloading (and re-loading) generally works fine in my Ruby (`2.3.0`) on Rails (`5.0.1`) project. However, in development mode I occasionally see an error like the following:

> Unable to autoload constant Foo::Bar, expected /app/models/foo/bar.rb to define it

This is unexpected because:

1. The first request worked fine (it autoloaded once already).
2. It only appears after editing code and sending a new request.
3. It does not always happen. I cannot figure out why *sometimes* it fails to reload.
4. The file (`foo/bar.rb`) does, in fact, define `Foo::Bar`.

Moreover, the code for `foo/bar.rb` is dead simple:

```
module Foo
  class Bar < CustomRecord
  end
end
```

The simple work-around is to restart the server and then send the request again (which always succeeds). FWIW, I'm using [`zeus server`](https://github.com/burke/zeus).

My best-guess is that something is not being reloaded, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging. I can't seem to point to any specific action which causes the problem. Sometimes editing code causes it to happen, sometimes not.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using Ruby 2.2.4 and Rails 4.2. It happens only in my test environment, only if I've modified code, and only if I'm running tests individually--running the entire test suite has no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of good explanations for Rails autoloading behavior that you can find. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548183/3703449) provides a useful explanation, which it grabs from [this blog post at urbanautomaton.com](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/).

Summary:

Basically, Rails first uses Ruby's constant lookup. If that fails, then it has its own lookup, which will miss files if

- They are not in the autoload paths (Rails won't find app/foo/bar.rb if `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/foo)` is not added to config/application.rb)
- The directory name/namespace convention isn't followed

It will find `Foo::Bar` in app/foo/bar.rb if it's defined as:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

but not

```
module Foo
  module Bar
  end
end
```

- A constant in a different namespace is referenced without that namespace indicated in another file that's already been autoloaded

Quote from the blog post describing what I mean:

> At this point, we’ve only seen how a single constant name maps to a
>   single file name. But as we know, a constant reference in Ruby can
>   resolve to a number of different constant definitions, which vary
>   depending on the nesting in which the reference was made. How does
>   Rails handle this?
>
> The answer is, “partially”. As `Module#const_missing` passes no nesting
>   information to the receiver, Rails does not know the nesting in which
>   the reference was made, and it must make an assumption. For any
>   reference to a constant `Foo::Bar::Baz`, it assumes the following:
>
> ```
> module Foo
>   module Bar
>     Baz # Module.nesting => [Foo::Bar, Foo]
> end
> ```
>
> end
>
> In other words, it assumes the maximum nesting possible for a given constant
>   reference. The example reference is therefore treated exactly the same
>   as the following:
>
> `Foo::Bar::Baz # Module.nesting => []`
>
> ```
> module Foo::Bar
>   Baz # Module.nesting => [Foo::Bar]
> end
> ```
>
> While there’s
>   been a significant loss of information, Rails does have some extra
>   information it can use. It knows that Ruby failed to resolve this
>   particular constant reference using its regular lookup, meaning that
>   whatever constant it should refer to cannot be already loaded.
>
> When `Foo::Bar::Baz` is referred to, then, Rails will attempt to load
>   the following constants in turn, until it finds one that is already
>   loaded:
>
> - `Foo::Bar::Baz`
> - `Foo::Baz`
> - `Baz`
>
> As soon as an already-loaded constant `Baz`
>   is encountered, Rails knows this cannot be the `Baz` it is looking for,
>   and the algorithm raises a `NameError`.

It's difficult to say what exactly is causing your problem(s) without more specifics about how your code is set up, but hopefully understanding what's going on with autoloading in Rails might help a little. I would highly recommend reading through the blog post and answer linked above.

**Edited for possible solution:**

Make sure 'app/models/foo' is added to your autoload_load paths in config/application.rb - or move 'foo' to app/models/concerns, which should be there by default.

Often adding explicit `require` statements helps - especially if things are loading properly in development but not in test. I recently solved this problem by adding a file that required all of my nested files (I had a directory structure that did not mirror my namespace structure) and then requiring that file in my test helper.

**Second edit**

Including information relevant to the question, why a constant might load successfully only once.

From [the same blog post](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/):

> If constants are loaded only when they’re first encountered at
>   runtime, then by necessity their load order depends on the individual
>   execution path. This can mean that the same constant reference
>   resolves to different constant definitions in two runs of the same
>   code. Worse still, the same constant reference twice in a row can give
>   different results.
>
> Let’s go back to our last example. What happens if we call .print_qux
>   twice?
>
> ```
> > Foo::Bar.print_qux
> I'm in Foo!
> => nil
> > Foo::Bar.print_qux
> ```
>
> NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::Qux This is disastrous!
>   First we’ve been given the wrong result, and then we’ve been
>   incorrectly told that the constant we referred to doesn’t exist. What
>   on earth led to this?
>
> The first time, as before, is down to the loss of nesting information.
>   Rails can’t know that Foo::Qux isn’t what we’re after, so once it
>   realises that Foo::Bar::Qux does not exist, it happily loads it.
>
> The second time, however, Foo::Qux is already loaded. So our reference
>   can’t have been to that constant, otherwise Ruby would have resolved
>   it, and autoloading would never have been invoked. So the lookup
>   terminates with a NameError, even though our reference could (and
>   should) have resolved to the as-yet-unloaded ::Qux.
>
> We can fix this by referring to ::Qux first, ensuring that it’s loaded
>   for Ruby to resolve the reference:
>
> ```
> > Qux
> => "I'm at the root!"
> > Foo::Bar.print_qux
> I'm at the root!
> => nil
> > Foo::Bar.print_qux
> I'm at the root!
> => nil
> ```
>
> A funny thing has happened here. In order to get correct behaviour, we
>   deliberately loaded the constant we needed before we used it (albeit
>   indirectly, by referring to it, rather than loading the file that
>   defined it).
>
> But wait; isn’t this suspiciously close to explicitly loading our
>   dependencies with require, the very thing autoloading was supposed to
>   save us from?
>
> To be fair, we could also have fixed the issue by fully qualifying all
>   of our constant references, i.e. making sure that within .print_qux we
>   referred to ::Qux and not the ambiguous Qux. But this still costs us
>   our existing intuitions about Ruby’s behaviour. Moreover, without
>   intimate knowledge of the autoloading process, we would have been hard
>   pressed to deduce that this was necessary.

Comment: As I explained in the question, the class auto-loads just fine *the first time*. I definitely have all the naming and paths set up correctly, or it would not autoload the first time. None of your explanation addresses the issue I described. Notice that I was very clear that the error is **SPURIOUS** and that the first request (and even second and third!) worked fine.

Comment: The blog post specifically addresses why the constant would be loaded on the first request and not again, which is why I found it relevant. I made a mistake by overlooking that part in my answer, not because I didn't read and understand your question but because I overlooked the fact that  my summary should include that part, and I will edit it accordingly.