# Getting a NameError: uninitialized constant error upgrading to Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am upgrade ruby to ver 3.1.3, rails ver 6.1
And I got error NameError: uninitialized constant

My folder tree:

```
- app
 |- models
   |- area.rb
   |- area
     |- search.rb
     |- constants.rb
```

In search.rb

```
module Area::Search
 include do
  # some functions here
 end
end
```

In area.rb

```
class Area < ApplicationRecord
 include Area::Search

 # some method here
end
```

In ./config/application.rb I custom directories for autoloading
`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]`

Then I run `rails zeitwerk:check`
I get an error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Area

module Area::Search
       ^^^^
Did you mean?  Arel
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of circular dependency.

Think about it this way, which file should be loaded first?

If it's search.rb, it will find `Area::Search` with `Area` undefined.

If it's area.rb, it will find `include Area::Search` with `Area` defined, but `Search` undefined.

Neiter file can be loaded without the other.

Change the definition of `Area::Search` to

```
class Area < ApplicationRecord
  module Search
    include do
      # some functions here
    end
  end
end
```

Or rename the namespace to something other than `Area` so it could be a module like `Areas`.

Or define the `Search` module inside the `Area` class in the `area.rb` file if they are tightly coupled.

Comment: area folder is just an example, this issue appear when I use `include Base::ImgixImage` from `./models/base/imgix_image.rb` into `area.rb` too

Comment: I can find solution on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545602/rails-unable-to-autoload-constant-from-file-despite-being-defined-in-that-file